# Which is more efficient? Using the same arraylist by using removeAll() or creating the new arraylist

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, collections

Im using arraylist to compare the elements in my selenium webdriver script in which I have compare the elemets from two different pages.

So which one is more efficient ?

Using same arraylist or creating the new one?

Comment: Most of the times I would create a new Arraylist and let the garbage collector decompose the list items references in its own sweet time.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for removeAll()(As defined in AbstractCollection):

```
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(c);
    boolean modified = false;
    Iterator<?> it = iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (c.contains(it.next())) {
            it.remove();
            modified = true;
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

The source code for clear()(As defined in ArrayList):

```
public void clear() {
    modCount++;

    // clear to let GC do its work
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        elementData[i] = null;

    size = 0;
}
```

clear() is much faster since it doesn't have to deal with all those extra method calls, but **I think that instantiate a new ArrayList is the most efficient, in particular in a very big ArrayList (no need to iterate over the collection).**